# How to find the Average of element in xQuery?

Tags: database, xquery

### Find the names of the departments that have the average salary greater than 5000

I have XML Code like this.

```
<emps>
    <employee ename="Ramesh">
        <department>
            <name>IT</name> 
            <salary>6000</salary>
        </department>
    </employee>
    <employee ename="Ram">
        <department>
            <name>IT</name> 
            <salary>16000</salary>
        </department>
    </employee>

     <employee ename="Sam">
        <department>
            <name>Sales</name> 
            <salary>1000</salary>
        </department>
    </employee>
</emps>
```

And the expected output is following. IT is the only department with average salary higher than 5000

```
<department>IT</department>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an `avg` function and in XQuery 3 and later you can easily group items with the `group by` clause of a FLOWR expression:

```
for $dep in //department
group by $name := $dep/name
where avg($dep/salary) > 5000
return <department>{$name}</department>
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDbr